# Firebase get deeper node by field

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the following structure in my database:
[image]

```
var pathFriend = "stuff/"+ userKey;                    
admin.database().ref(pathFriend).orderByChild("sale").equalTo(true).once("value", function(snapshotItem) {
                            snapshotItem.forEach(function(data) {
                                console.log("key = "+ data.key);
                            });
                    });
```

The question is how can I search by two fields with boolean values?
Thanks.

Comment: You can't search by multiple fields with Realtime Database.  You can with Firestore.

Comment: @DougStevenson is it make sense to migrate to Firestore? Is it an easy thing?

Comment: That depends entirely on your situation.  Firestore is going to be preferred in the future, so it's worth looking into.

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase